# Altium error: "Could not find closed shape" when creating region from primitives

Tags: altium, layout

I have imported a dxf onto mechanical layers, and want to use this to create the pads for a component footprint.

My approach is to select the whole outline of the would-be-pad on the mechanical layer, use "Tools -> Convert -> Create region from selected primitives", change the region's layer to the top layer, and then place a pad inside the region to assign the designator.

When I click "Tools -> Convert -> Create region from selected primitives" I get the error message:

*"Could not find closed shape using primitives centerline due to the following error:
Multiple paths found from location: (-0.15, 0.15)
Would you like to try finding closed shape using primitives external edges instead?"*

[image]

I have checked the position of (-0.15, 0.15) and it is a point where an arc meets a line. There appears to be no overlap and no duplicates at this point.

I am using Altium Designer v15.1.

Edit: This is what it looks like when I select the area around (-0.15, 0.15).
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This confirmation message appears when the shape has ambiguities. E.g. it happens if an arc meets a line **and** there is an additional round element overlaying the end of the line.

So try to select the arc-line joint with the mouse by spanning up a small area surrounding that joint. Here is an example:

[image]

You need to remove that additional element in order to get rid of the confirmation message.

Comment: Useful answer @Stefan Wyss. I've already checked for any extra primitives on the relevant layer, both using your method and also by scrolling through the component primitives in the PCB library. There's nothing that is not needed as part of the outline.

Comment: @CHA108 This has always worked for me, but I have more recent versions of Altium. Things you could try: 1) Zoom in to the MAX at the point in question until you see the grid and confirm that endpoints are on grid. 2) Try a simpler shape and check if they have the same problem.